# How do I write a TypeScript interface for a React component as a static property on another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple component like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const Card: React.SFC<CardPropDef> = ({
  children,
  className,
  ...args,
}) => (
  <div
    className={classNames('card', className)}
    {...args}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
);

Card.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
};

interface CardPropDef {
  children: any;
  className?: string;
}

const CardSection: React.SFC<CardSectionPropDef> = ({
  children,
  types = [],
  ...args,
}) => {
  const classes = classNames(
    'card__section',
    types.map(type => `card__section--${type}`),
  );
  return (
    <div className={classes} {...args}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

interface CardSectionPropDef {
  types: string[];
  children: any;
}

Card.Section = CardSection;

export default Card;
```

Where you would access Card sections like so:

```
<Card.Section>
    Contents
</Card.Section>
```

But I'm confused on how to write or extend the definition to include the section as property on the Card SFC.

My linter highlights the problem:

> Property 'Section' does not exist on type 'StatelessComponent'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotation:

```
const Card: React.SFC<CardPropDef>
```

Means its only a React.SFC and does not have a `Section` property. You can type it accordingly as an [intersection](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html) if you want :

```
const Card: React.SFC<CardPropDef> & { Section : AddYourTypeHere }
```

Comment: Thanks, went for: `const Card: React.SFC<CardPropDef> & { Section?: React.SFC<CardSectionPropDef> }` in the end, since declaring the property after initialization means it's still not there (so throws a lint warning).